# The equality persists after addition to one of the sides

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Assume $a\le \epsilon +b$ for all $\epsilon >0$. The book says that it implies $a\le b$. However, It seems to me that **the equality should break after the addition of $\epsilon>0$**. How can it be possible?

---

**If you need the context**, it's from the proof of Theorem 3.10 (a) in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by *Walter Rudin*. He proves $\text{diam}\,\bar{E}=\text{diam}\,E$ by showing both $$\text{diam}\,\bar{E}\le2\epsilon+\text{diam}\,E$$ and $$\text{diam}\,E\le\text{diam}\,\bar{E}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "equality should break"?

Comment: @ZacharySelk It means, if $\text{diam}\,\bar{E}\le2\epsilon+\text{diam}\,E$ leads to $\text{diam}\,\bar{E}<\text{diam}\,E$, I sense no problem (note that $\le$ is not used).

Comment: Well, is it true that $a\le \epsilon+a$ for all $\epsilon>0$? If that's true, then it's possible for the statements "$a\le \epsilon+b$ for all $\epsilon>0$" and "$a=b$" to both be true.

Comment: @JoeyZou Isn't it more fit to say $a<\epsilon+a$ for all $\epsilon>0$? The equality makes it somewhat weird, **but I'm not saying that you're wrong...** I just don't get how I can get the same thing after adding to it...!

Comment: But it is true that $a\le \epsilon+a$ for all $\epsilon>0$, right?

Comment: @JoeyZou Yes. I know you're right. I'm just suffering internally....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a>b$. Then $\dfrac{a-b}2>0$ and setting $\epsilon=\dfrac{a-b}2$ gives $a\le\dfrac{a-b}2+b$, i.e. $a\le b$, contradicting the assumption $a>b$. Therefore we must have $a\le b$.

Comment: Your answer certainly makes sense, although I don't quite get it **intuitively**.

Comment: @Il-seobBae: Intuitively, think of $(b+ε)$ as a hand pressing down on $a$ as $ε$ is decreased towards $0$. Where can $a$ go? It can't stay above $b$ by any positive amount perpetually, because eventually $ε$ will go below any positive amount. Therefore in the end $a$ must end up at $b$ or below.